# Angular's E2E for backend testing

Tags: angularjs, backend

can angular's e2e framework be used for testing web services and also for database validations ... in short for backend testing or it is just to test UI i.e. front end testing ?

Answer (score 1):

Karma e2e can be used to run tests that include pulling data from a remote server. So yes, it could be used to test a web service, in as much as you could test 'when I make a request to THIS url, expect THIS response'.

Comment: Thanks S McCrohan ... in continuation with my question above ... what are the limitations of karma e2e over selenium or vice-versa

Comment: That's a much better, more specific question, and I can't answer it because I haven't used selenium. But I'd guess that posting that as a new question (so it's more noticable) will probably get some good responses.